# How do I delete .svn files with total commander?

Tags: total-commander

I want to delete all svn files in a folder and its subfolder with Total Commander.

I tried searching for `*.svn` and in advanced tab I checked hiddens file on.

But, I still get "[No files found]", what can I do to find those files?

Comment: What is the version of Tatal Commander? Do you see those folders in tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set Configuration>Display>Show hidden/system files?

.svn is not a file but a directory. So if you want to select the attributes (you actualy don't need this), then you must also select "Directory"

Comment: i changed my search to svn only and did what you said. And your right about the Directory part. thanks alot.

Comment: Some more detail on how to do this: Go to Configuration | Options | Display and make sure the "Show hidden/system files" checkbox is clicked. Go to Commands | Search.  Type .svn into the Search for textbox.  Go to the Advanced tab: click on Attributes and tick only the "Directory" checkbox. Like XHelp said, the svn files that keep track of your version control info are all saved in .svn directories.

Answer (score 6):

As for me, I search .svn, then I see a list of directories, press "Feed to listbox", Ctrl+A, Shift+Delete. It works great in Total Command 7.50.

Comment: Where do I find Feed to listbox? I'm new to TC

Comment: after search is complete, you'll see that button at the right-bottom corner

Answer (score 1):

To do it with a button, build a bat file, for example called "deleteSvn.bat" with this code:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S *.svn*') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"
if not errorlevel 1 goto final
echo Removed all .svn folders
pause
:final
pause
```

create a command button and assign as the path to run the bat such as d:\bats\deleteSvn.bat

Then use the button at the root of the folder from which you want to delete .svn